# CSS continious animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following CSS code;
The problem here is that the animation works how I want to but it resets after the 10 seconds are done which just looks ugly. Ideally I would like to have an infinite animation that instead of restarting simply wraps the image so when the left side of the image is out of canvas it comes back from the right side.

```
@keyframes scrollRight {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 30%;
  }
  
  100% {
    background-position-x: 130%;
  }
}

.onrir {
  background-image: url('./text.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.8px #fff;
  font-size: 10rem;
  line-height: 100%;
  background-size: 120% 120%;
  background-position: 30% -30%;

  animation: scrollRight 10s infinite linear forwards;
}
```

I have no idea how to implement this outside of keyframes.

Edit: html + tailwind code to go with this.

```
<h1 class="font-bold text-center text-white">
        <span class="onrir xs text-transparent bg-clip-text"> Who am I? </span>
</h1>
```

Text.svg:
https://pastebin.mozilla.org/X0reUcSD

Comment: Remove "forwards"

Comment: @Gerard sadly that did not fix my issue. It remains exactly the same after doing so.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @imhvost this is with tailwind ```<h1 class="font-bold text-center text-white">
  <span class="onrir xs text-transparent bg-clip-text"> Who am I? </span>
 </h1>```

Comment: text.svg is still missing

Comment: @ATP sorry about that. I've edited it on the main post.

Comment: it looks like this: https://imgur.com/DJmvqyM after zoom

Comment: @Cosmos didn't get what you want, and can't guess from the example. if you want to split the image , you would need JS, or  second  element that acts as the cropped part.